# OpenCV : Contour Detection Android contourldx problems

Tags: java, opencv, contour, android

I am able to detect the Contour in an image using C++. However, I want to convert it in Android using java lang. So, i make it using android studio.
(partly because I am a JAVA newbie)

Then i found some problems, When i run it, i had a error problems with this code :

> if(contours[contourIdx].size()>100)

in this main program.

```
 @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
        mHsv = new Mat(height,width,CvType.CV_8UC3);
        hierarchy = new Mat();
        mHsvMask = new Mat();
        mDilated = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    }
@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    mRgba.release();
    mHsv.release();
    mHsvMask.release();
    mDilated.release();
    hierarchy.release();

}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba =inputFrame.rgba();
    mHsv = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV, 3);
    hierarchy.release();
    Scalar lowerThreshold = new Scalar ( 120, 100, 100 ); 
    Scalar upperThreshold = new Scalar ( 179, 255, 255 ); 
    Core.inRange ( mHsv, lowerThreshold , upperThreshold, mHsvMask );

    Imgproc.dilate ( mHsvMask, mDilated, new Mat() );
    Imgproc.findContours(mDilated, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    for ( int contourIdx=0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++ )
    {
        if(contours[contourIdx].size()>100)  // Minimum size allowed for consideration
        {
            Imgproc.drawContours ( mRgba, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0,255,0) , -5);
        }
    }
    return mRgba;
}
}
```

Hopefully, someone has some experience in this. Thanks..

Comment: You can learn about open cv from some books which you can get from http://www.filtrlink.com and search for opencv in the search box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the area concept

```
 if(Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx))>100) {
             Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255), 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, new Point());
         }
```

Comment: tick the answer Bagus W if it really works and helps you